# Can't get access to the Java DB (Embedded) using NetBeans utilities

Tags: java, netbeans, derby, embedded-database, javadb

stackoverflowers!!!

I've got a big problem with creating embedded database, using NetBeans IDE. So, this are the steps I'm taking to create app:

1 - In Services I'm starting the server.
2 - Then creating the database;
3 - Making a connection, using a JavaDB (Embedded) driver;
4 - Then, in a new connection I'm creating a new table;
5 - Then I'm creating empty Java application project;
6 - Creating an Entity Classes from Database file;
7 - Making Frame Form with a table;
8 - Binding the table with databases table;
9 - Click Run button;
10 - NetBeans says: "database was not found";

SO, your suggestions? I'm so tired with that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a pretty good explanation about your scenario [here](http://aparna-java.blogspot.in/2011/11/good-day-all.html). If you are using `NetBeans` then it is perfectly good. 
As, once I faced the same scenario and found that there are very few resources about the topic, but this post particularly solved my problem.

I did not mention the details about the answer as the mentioned link speaks it all.

Thanks, hope it helps!!!